# Can Lists cope with a million items?

Tags: python, csv

I am slowly developing a data processing application in Python 2.6 (*). My test data are very small, like 5000 cases, but it is expected that there will be a million cases in the near future and I wondering if my current approach is workable under those conditions.

Structure of the problem:
I have two csv files, one contains call (5000 rows, 20 columns) and another one details for a call (500 rows, 10 columns). I have to build a third csv file which will contain all cases from the "call" file where additional details where found. Behind the scenes there is some heavy lifting going on (merging and restructuring data in the details list, data comparison between lists). 
But I am very nervous about building the output list: at the moment the code looks like this:

```
def reduceOutputListToPossibleMatches(outputList, detailsList):
    reducedList = list()

    for outputItem in outputList:
        isFound = False
        for detailsItem in detailsList:
            if detailsItem[14] == outputItem[4]:
                if isfound:
                    detailsItem[30] = "1" #ambigous case
                                          # - more than one match was found
# 1 is an indicator for true - I am not using python here because spss has no support for booleans.
                isFound = True
        if isFound:
            reducedList.append(detailsItem )

    return reducedList
```

I think that this algorithm will take a very long time, simply because I have to loop about two large lists.
So my questions boils down to: How fast are lists in Python and are there better alternatives? Additionally: The double-List are somewhat inconvenient to handle, because I have to remember the index position of each column - is there a better alternative?

*=I am calling SPSS Version 19 later on, which refuses to work with newer versions of python.

Comment: why not work with iterables? something like `isFound: yield detailsItem`

Comment: https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity in particular, get, set and append are all O(1). so it's fast.

Comment: the algorithm looks like O(n^2), which is not so good for n=1000000. isn't it better idea to use some SQL database?

Comment: @Elazar Could you please elaborate? I am quite unfamiliar with python

Comment: I'll try to put it as an "answer".

Comment: there's probably a faster way but I cannot figure out what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Karoly, both files have a column for a telephone number. The problem is, there can be mulitple cases with this number in the OutputList. The DetailsList contains a cases which can be in the Outputlist. 
The result should contain all Items from the OutputList which are also in the DetailsList - cases with multiple records have to resolved later on.

Comment: apart from the multiple cases, set intersection is what you are looking for.

Comment: If I understand sets correctly, the elements must be unique - which I cannot guarantee, there can be duplicate numbers in both Lists.
Think of a telephone hotline which can be called N times by a person. Said person can rate the hotline afterwards, which he can do possibly multiple times...

Comment: There are certain syntax and semantic errors in the code presented here. please fix them so it will be easier to understand. (`detailsItem in [14] == outputItem[4]:` is nonsense, and `detailsList[30] = "1"` is probably not what you meant)

Comment: You could also look at using Cython - Check this out - [Faster Code Using Static Typing](http://docs.cython.org/src/quickstart/cythonize.html).

Comment: @Elazar: I am sorry, i have fixed it. The ="1" statement indicates true - I cannot use a true boolean because SPSS does not have such a value and will read the result later on.

Comment: Is there anything special about `detailsList[30]` then? it's the main list, you see. Not the iteration variable.

Comment: Copy and paste error - it should be the Iteam. Thank you for pointing this out - I am looking too much on the same lines of code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From Elazar's answer, using a dict to avoid the inner loop:

```
def reduceOutputListToPossibleMatches(outputList, detailsList):
    details = {}
    for detailsItem in detailsList:
        key = detailsItem[14]
        if key in details:
            details[key][30] = "1"
        else:
            details[key] = detailsItem

    for outputItem in outputList:
        key = outputItem[4]
        if key in details:
            yield details[key]

res = reduceOutputListToPossibleMatches(outputList, detailsList)
with open('somefile', 'w') as f:
    f.writelines(res)
```

If you need all of the ambiguous lines:

```
def reduceOutputListToPossibleMatches(outputList, detailsList):
    details = {}
    for detailsItem in detailsList:
        key = detailsItem[14]
        if key in details:
            details[key].append(detailsItem)
        else:
            details[key] = [detailsItem]

    for outputItem in outputList:
        key = outputItem[4]
        if key in details:
            for item in details[key]:
                if len(details[key]) > 1:
                    item[30] = "1"
                yield item

res = reduceOutputListToPossibleMatches(outputList, detailsList)
with open('somefile', 'w') as f:
    f.writelines(res)
```

Comment: Nice. A `try: yield; except` will avoid double lookup

Comment: @Elazar, true but whenever I've timed this the double lookup is always faster and I find it clearer too. YMMV.

Comment: Good to know. Come to think about it, this will probably be a small dict [EDIT: well, no. I was wrong]. Do you know about a specific optimization done for this case in `dict`?

Comment: For the second function, wouldn't `defaultdict` be more suitable/faster?

Comment: @Duncan: That looks very good! Thank you very much. I will try this :)

Comment: @Elazar, defaultdict would certainly work, it is a bit cleaner but I think also a bit slower. What do you mean about the assignment to `key` being overridden?

Comment: @Duncan Sorry, ignore it. I sometimes misread `if x in iter` as `for x in iter` for some reason. Second time this week. :(

Answer (score 2):

I think you don't need to return a `list`. You can do something like this:

```
def reduceOutputListToPossibleMatches(outputList, detailsList):
    for outputItem in outputList:
        isFound = False
        for detailsItem in detailsList:
            if detailsItem[14] == outputItem[4]: #there was a syntax error here
                if isfound:
                    detailsItem[30] = "1"
                    break
                isFound = True
        else:
            yield detailsItem

res = reduceOutputListToPossibleMatches(outputList, detailsList)
with open('somefile', 'w') as f:
    f.writelines(res)
```

But it's still `O(n**2)` which is pretty slow. Maybe an SQL database (through Django?) will be more suitable for this task.

Small changes to @Duncan's suggestion:

```
from collections import defaultdict
def reduceOutputListToPossibleMatches(outputList, detailsList):
    details = defaultdict(list)
    for detailsItem in detailsList:
        key = detailsItem[14]
        details[key].append(detailsItem)

    for outputItem in outputList:
        val = details[outputItem[4]]
        if len(val) > 1:
            for item in val:
                item[30] = "1"
        yield from val
```

Comment: Thank you very muc - the generator looks promising, but I think you are right: It will be slow - how slo, I would have to profile, unfortuanetly, the "live" data are the first test case for this.
I stumpled upon PyTables - I will check if it's useful.

Comment: Python has sqlite3 included by default. For all your sql (lite) needs. Seriously its very fast and completely standard with CPython. [sqlite python documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html)

Comment: @Serdalis so you agree with the SQL idea? I think that should be a simple join, but even this will be O(n^2) on the server side.

Comment: sqlite is good, but for this it is probably overkill. All you need to do is convert detailsList into a dictionary using `detailsItem[14]` as key and updating column 30 for any duplicates. Then the inner for loop becomes one dictionary lookup.

Comment: @duncan A dictionary requeies unique items, which is not achievable for this list.

Comment: @ChristianSauer but your original code only uses one of the ambiguous lines. If you need them all then just store a list of them off each key.

Comment: @Duncan I'd like to see 1 million items stored in a database instead of a csv anyway. So extending that logic sqlite would be perfect. But yes for a simple algorithm it's overkill.

Comment: @Serdalia: I agree! I would love some rational data storage technique, but in my field of work throwing around csvs or xlsx files is state of the art.